# Windows 10 fail to boot with 0xc0000001 error code

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot

**Introduction**

Hello, I'm running multiboot installation on machine with UEFI. I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu installed, managed by Grub at startup and I have laptop working like this for about half a year. By the time... I'm using Windows 10 very rarely I rather use linux for my everyday work. But yesterday I need to, and very disturbing BSOD appeared.

```
Recovery
Your PC couldn't start properly
A required device isn't connected or can't be acessed
Error code 0xc0000001
```

[image]

- I can't log into safe mode. System just hangs at the boot screen and shutdown laptop itself after couple of minutes.
- I haven't made any hardware changes ever.
- I haven't made any driver changes.
- I do not mess up with any Windows directory but I have Windows partition mounted in Ubuntu.
- I do not touch EFI partition recently.
- Last time I have using Windows installation is about 2 weeks ago.
- System sometimes instead of showing BSOD, hangs at the boot screen.
- restore default BIOS settings doesn't change anything

I have googling for fixes for hours. So I made USB with my Windows 10 installation (exactly the same from which I have Windows installed) and run Windows Recovery Envoirnemt. My laptop is hp 8560w.

**Windows Recovery Environment**

System restore

I got message. "*To use System Restore, you must specify which Windows Installation to restore. Restart this computer, select an Operating System and then select System Restore.*"

Automatic repair

Fails - with no information in event log.

Reset your pc

I got message. "*The drive where Windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again.*"

**Windows Command Prompt**

*S: is my EFI partition*

```
chkdsk c: /f /v /r /b /offlinescanandfix
```

no problems found

```
sfc /scannow /offbootdir=*s:\ /offwindir=c:\windows
```

no problems found

```
Bootrec /fixmbr
```

nothing changes

```
Bootrec /fixboot
```

nothing changes

```
Bootrec /scanos
```

windows found

```
Bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

message *"The requested system device cannot be found."*

```
del s:\* /s /q
bcdboot c:\windows /s s: /f UEFI
```

nothing changes
I even format EFI partition and make it again.

**Summary**

My `bcdedit /store s:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD`

[image]

Ubuntu still works fine so AFAIK it's not hard drive or GPT issue.
I can't login to recovery mode by Shift + F8 but I had never could. So I don't think it matters especially that fixing by Windows Recovery Mode from USB work neither.
It seems to be ridicolous for me that Microsoft provide not even detail but in fact any useful information about why system fail to boot.
Pleas do not tell me to contact hp support because I really doubt that they help me.

Is there any other way to fix it or reinstalling Windows is my only chance.

Comment: There is no specific cause for the 0xc0000001 error code which is the reason more information can't be given to you the end user.  Just because Ubuntu currently works, does not mean the partition, that Windows was on didn't have a problem.   Your `sfc /scannow` syntax seems strange.  The fact you are unable to Reset your installation indicates a hard failure with Windows.  Its unlikely you will be able to recover from this particular crash.  Your sfc error is easy to fix, delete c:\windows\winsxs\pending.xml, and try again.

Comment: 0xc0000001 is usually file system corruption, try deleting the pending xml as suggested and try booting again. If no joy boot into the recovery environment and open a command prompt and run a chkdsk on the drive.

Comment: Try steps outlined in "Fix - The drive where Windows is installed is locked" (https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/The_drive_where_Windows_is_installed_is_locked.html). You should use Windows 10 installation / recovery media for repairing issue - boot it UEFI way !!!

Answer (score 0):

> Error code 0xc0000001 on Windows 10 has been reported by some users when attempting to install Windows 10. When you encounter this error, the setup will be on a loop and the error message will keep popping up.
>
> Here are some methods that will help you fix the error code 0xc0000001 while trying to install Windows 10. Do not perform these methods unless you’re absolutely confident you can do it properly. Otherwise, you might make things worse.
>
> Method 1: Convert drive/partition to GPT
>
> If you need to manually wipe the drive and then convert it to GPT, follow these steps:
>
> Step 1: Power down your computer and put your Windows 10 installation DVD or USB drive
>
> Step 2: Boot your computer to the USB or DVD key in UEFI mode.
>
> Step 3: Once you’re at the Windows 10 Setup, press the Shift+F10 keys. This will open the command prompt window.
>
> Step 4: Open diskpart tool from CMD. Just type diskpart and enter.
>
> Step 5: Then, type list disk on CMD again. Press enter. This will allow you to identify your computer’s drive that you want to reformat.
>
> Step 6: Choose the drive and reformat it by typing the following on the command prompt:
>
> ```
> select disk <disk number> (press enter)
> clean (press enter)
> convert gpt (press enter)
> exit (press enter)
> ```
>
> Step 7: Proceed with the Windows 10 Setup installation.
>
> Note: when you’re prompted to choose the installation type, make sure to choose Custom. Then, choose unallocated space and click Next. This will automatically start the installation of Windows 10.
>
> Method 2: Use Media Creation Tool to Perform Automatic Repair
>
> Automatic Repair is a Windows feature/utility that allows you to fix certain system problems preventing you from installing or starting Windows. It works by scanning your computer system for any potential problem and tries to fix it.
>
> Step 1: Download the Media Creation Tool
>
> Step 2: Boot your computer using the Windows 10 DVD, or the System Repair disc. When you’re asked to press any key to boot, just press any key on your keyboard.
>
> Step 3: Choose the right time and the keyboard type.
>
> Step 4: Click Repair your computer. You’ll see this at the lower left corner on your screen.
>
> Step 5: Choose Troubleshoot from Choose an option screen
>
> Step 6: Click advanced options
>
> Step 7: Choose automatic repair
>
> This will automatically run the utility.

You can find the above text, and a few other suggestions on how to rectify that [error message in this article](http://errortools.com/windows/fix-error-code-0xc0000001-on-windows-10/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after modifying Debian partitions on a Debian / Windows 10 dual-boot system. The setup was similar: UEFI, GPT, only the Debian partitions were modified... boot failure... booted from USB into Windows recovery and recreated the bootloader on the EFI boot partition with `bcdedit` as above... still the error.

I noticed an extra `C:\EFI` directory in the root of the main Windows partition. I have no idea how it got there. I deleted it (`rd /s C:\EFI`) and the Windows boot started working. Note that during my repair attempts I was careful to use `bcedit` with a proper destination flag of the boot partition (after assigning a drive letter to it using `diskpart`). I suppose Grub or some sort of Windows update could have stuffed the extra `C:\EFI` directory into the Windows partition but I'm just guessing.